# Cannot post error during node.js search to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I run **node.js** with `mongoose` to autocomplete search function as follows
from github : https://github.com/gabrieleromanato/Node.js-Search-Autocomplete

And I clicked the search button while run I this **app.js** 
, I get the error `CANNOT POST` with

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

How to solve this error?

**app.js:**

```
 const express = require('express');
 const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const path = require('path');
 const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
 const app = express();


 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));


 mongoose.Promise = Promise;
 /*mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/users');*/


 var promise = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/users', {
   useMongoClient: true
 });

 promise.on('error', console.error);
 promise.once('open', function(){
     // CONNECTED TO MONGODB SERVER
     console.log("Connected to mongod server");
 });

 const Users = require('./models/Users');

 app.disable('x-powered-by');

 app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({extname: '.hbs'}));

 app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
 app.set('env', 'development');


 app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'favicon.png')));
 app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public'), {
   maxAge: 0,
   dotfiles: 'ignore',
   etag: false
 }));

 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


 app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Users.find().limit(6).then(usrs => {
     res.render('index', {
       pageTitle: 'Node Search',
       users: usrs
     });
   }).catch(err => {
       res.sendStatus(401);
   });

 });

 app.post('/search', function(req, res) {


   let q = req.body.query;
   let query = {
     "$or": [{"name.first": {"$regex": q, "$options": "i"}}, {"name.last": {"$regex": q, "$options": "i"}}]
   };
   let output = [];

   Users.find(query).limit(6).then( usrs => {
       if(usrs && usrs.length && usrs.length > 0) {
           usrs.forEach(user => {
             let obj = {
                 id: user.name.first + ' ' + user.name.last,
                 label: user.name.first + ' ' + user.name.last
             };
             output.push(obj);
           });
       }
       res.json(output);
   }).catch(err => {
     res.sendStatus(400);
   });

 });


 if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
   app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
     res.status(err.status || 500);
   });
 }

 app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
   res.status(err.status || 500);
 });

 app.listen(port);
```

Thanks in advance.